# What does this union of functions represent?

Tags: set-theory

I'm reading Kenneth Kunen - The Foundations of Mathematics (2009) and on page 46 whilst proving the theorem about primitive recursion on $\mathbb{ON}$, he defines $f$ as a union of functions. But gives no other clues as to how this is supposed to be interpreted. I tried thinking about it in a few ways but it did not make any sense. Any ideas would be appreciated!

[image: Text]

Comment: In set theory a *function* is a set (of pairs); thus, it is "usual" union of sets. Obviously, the result will be itself a set of pairs.

Comment: This assumes that the functions domains are disjoint; otherwise the union is a relation rather than a function.

Comment: Kunen defines functions formally in Section I7.

Comment: If you take the Union of a bunch of functions, which all agree on the same domain, then the Union is itself a function. This is sometimes called a coherence property, f, and g cohere, if when restricted to the same domain, they are equal. This is because a function  requires each x to only be paired with one y. If the functions were ever unequal, for the same x; then you wouldnt have a function, you'd just have a binary relation. Note: To @Jean-ArmandMoroni point, if the functions have disjoint domains, then vacuously they must agree on the same domain. ( The cannot disagree on the same x )